# PHP: Passing variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a problem with a simple php file in which I am trying to pass a variable from php to javascript. I have used the exact same code successfully in  a more complex program, but cannot get it to work in the most trivial context here. Below is the entire code. When I run it, it complains that xxx is an unidentified variable:

```
<?php
    echo "<h2 style='text-align: center'>Welcome</h2><br>";
    echo '<script>var xxx = "Hello";</script>'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            echo xxx;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know there are other ways to pass data from php to js, but this one is simplest and I have used it before. Why is it failing here?

Comment: because there is no echo in JavaScript....

Comment: Additionally, it is invalid HTML to have output before the DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing php and JavaScript syntax

```
<script>
    echo xxx;
</script>
```

needs to be

```
<script>
   console.log(xxx);
</script>
```

ANd the php code should be in the body if you are outputting HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
    echo "<h2 style='text-align: center'>Welcome</h2><br>";
    echo '<script>var xxx = "Hello";</script>'
?>
        <script>
            console.log(xxx);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass the value. Use ID as the parameter.

```
  <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('NO').onchange = disablefield;
                document.getElementById('YES').onchange = disablefield;
        }</script>
echo "<tr><td width='50%'><input type='radio' name='item' value='A' id='YES'>YES</td><td><input type='radio' name='item' value='B' id='NO'>NO</td></tr>";
```